# Magento - Grand Total To Be Charged on Invoice

Tags: php, magento

When a customer buys something from a Magento store they receive an email confirmation which includes a line at the bottom for "Grand Total To Be Charged".  This shows the total in the stores base currency.

I would like to add this figure to the invoices which get printed from the backend.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

Lets see what is going on.
As we can see from the url (www.example.com/index.php/admin/sales_invoice/view/invoice_id/[some_id]/) `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_InvoiceController`'s `view` action is executed and this is corresponds to `<adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_view>` layout (app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/sales.xml) node. There we can see this:

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_view>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_invoice_view" name="sales_invoice_view">
...
```

We can see there that top block is `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Invoice_View`. There we can see (at the end of `__construct()` method):

```
if ($this->getInvoice()->getId()) {
    $this->_addButton('print', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print'),
        'class'     => 'save',
        'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\''.$this->getPrintUrl().'\')'
        )
    );
}
```

and

```
public function getPrintUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/print', array(
        'invoice_id' => $this->getInvoice()->getId()
    ));
}
```

Here we can see that our invoice PDF is created from a `print` action of current module/controller so lets see `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_InvoiceController` again and search for a required action method:

```
/**
 * Create pdf for current invoice
 */
public function printAction()
{
    $this->_initInvoice();
    parent::printAction();
}
```

and in parent `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Sales_Invoice`:

```
public function printAction()
{
    if ($invoiceId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('invoice_id')) {
        if ($invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->load($invoiceId)) {
            $pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_invoice')->getPdf(array($invoice));
            $this->_prepareDownloadResponse('invoice'.Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s').
                '.pdf', $pdf->render(), 'application/pdf');
        }
    }
    else {
        $this->_forward('noRoute');
    }
}
```

**As we can see the PDF is created by `sales/order_pdf_invoice` model (or `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice` class)**. Inside of a `getPdf()` method is a call `$this->insertTotals($page, $invoice);` which is defined in `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract` class. **My suggestion is to overwrite `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice` class and define there a custom `insertTotals($page, $invoice)` method to achieve what you need.** I decided to give a full picture of the situation to let you decide how to solve this task.

Useful link - [Overriding a model class in Magento](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how_to_override_magento_model_classes/)

Answer (score 2):

In short all you need to do is add some XML:

```
<global>
    <pdf>
       <totals>
            <mygrand_total translate="title">
                <title>Grand Total To Be Charged</title>
                <source_field>base_grand_total</source_field>
                <font_size>8</font_size>
                <display_zero>1</display_zero>
                <sort_order>705</sort_order>
            </mygrand_total>
       </totals>
    </pdf>
</global>
```

I would create a separate module under `app/code/local/Yourcompanyname/PDFBasetotal` and enable the module via `etc/modules/` after which create a `config.xml` file under `Yourcompanyname/PDFBasetotal/etc/` here I would add the above XML as to avoid any touching of core functionality.

As to why this works see the method below from the file: `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php`

Note the `$totals = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/pdf/totals')->asArray();` as this is what is looped over when creating the total output.

```
protected function _getTotalsList($source)
{
    $totals = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/pdf/totals')->asArray();
    usort($totals, array($this, '_sortTotalsList'));
    $totalModels = array();
    foreach ($totals as $index => $totalInfo) {
        if (!empty($totalInfo['model'])) {
            $totalModel = Mage::getModel($totalInfo['model']);
            if ($totalModel instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Total_Default) {
                $totalInfo['model'] = $totalModel;
            } else {
                Mage::throwException(
                    Mage::helper('sales')->__('PDF total model should extend Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Total_Default')
                );
            }
        } else {
            $totalModel = Mage::getModel($this->_defaultTotalModel);
        }
        $totalModel->setData($totalInfo);
        $totalModels[] = $totalModel;
    }

    return $totalModels;
}
```

Comment: I did this and it almost worked.  It adds the base total but with the wrong currency symbol.  You can see a snapshot from my invoice https://skitch.com/a1anm/efwnp/invoice2012-07-09-16-49-35.pdf-1-page The base total should actually be £93.33

Comment: Although your original question didn't mention currency difference, this should help `Mage::app()->getConfig()->getNode('default/'.Mage_Directory_Model_Currency::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_BASE);`

Comment: Where would I place this code? I believe my original question did mention the currency "..Grand Total To Be Charged. This shows the total in the stores base currency.". Your solution showed the total but not in the base currency (£). Instead it showed the currency the customer used when checking out.

Comment: My apologizes, I reread your question and there was some indication of currency difference. You may want to look into overriding `getTotalsForDisplay` in `/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Total/Default.php`